# dict comprehension discards elements

Tags: python, grouping, dictionary-comprehension

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

d = [{'k': 'v1'}]

r = ((k, v) for k, v in groupby(d, key=itemgetter('k')))
for k, v in r:
    print(k, list(v)) # v1 [{'k': 'v1'}]

print('---')
r = {k: v for k, v in groupby(d, key=itemgetter('k'))}
for k, v in r.items():
    print(k, list(v)) # v1 []
```

Seems like some quirk, or am I missing something?

Comment: As an aside, `r = ((k, v) for k, v in groupby(d, key=itemgetter('k')))` is totally pointless, it's the same as `r = groupby(d, key=itemgetter('k'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [documented part](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) of `itertools.groupby`:

> The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying iterable with groupby(). Because the source is shared, when the groupby() object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible. So, if that data is needed later, it should be stored as a list

In other words, you need to access the group before getting the next item in the iterator -- in this case, from inside the dict comprehension. To use it in a dict comprehension you need to make the list in the comprehension:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

d = [{'k': 'v1'}]

r = {k: list(v) for k, v in groupby(d, key=itemgetter('k'))}
for k, v in r.items():
    print(k, v) # v1 [{'k': 'v1'}]
```

In your first example, because you are using a generator expression, you don't actually start iterating the groupby iterator until you start the `for` loop. However, you would have the same issue if you used a non-lazy list comprehension instead of a generator (i.e. `r = [(k, v) for k, v in groupby(d, key=itemgetter('k'))]`).

#### Why does it work this way?

Preserving lazy iteration is the motivating idea behind itertools. Because it is dealing with (possibly large, or infinite) iterators, it never wants to store any values in memory. It just calls `next()` on the underlying iterator and does something with that value. Once you've called `next()` you can't go back to earlier values (without storing them, which itertools doesn't want to do).

With groupby it's easier to see with an example. Here is a simple generator that makes alternating ranges of positive and negative numbers and a groupby iterator that groups them:

```
def make_groups():
    i = 1
    while True:
        for n in range(1, 10):
            print("yielding: ", n*i)
            yield n * i
        i *= -1

g = make_groups()

grouper = groupby(g, key=lambda x: x>0)
```

`make_groups` prints a line each time `next()` is called before yielding the value to help know what's happening. When we call `next()` on  `grouper` this results in a next call to `g` and gets out first group and value:

```
> k, gr = next(grouper)
yielding:  1
```

Now each `next()` call on `gr` results in a `next()` call to the underlying `g` as you can see from the print:

```
> next(gr)
1              # already have this value from the initial next(grouper)
> next(gr)
yielding:  2   # gets the next value and clicks the underlying generator to the next yield
2
```

Now look what happens if we call `next()` on `grouper` to get the next group:

```
> next(grouper)

yielding:  3
yielding:  4
yielding:  5
yielding:  6
yielding:  7
yielding:  8
yielding:  9
yielding:  -1
```

Groupby is iterated through the generator until it hit a value that changed the key. The values have been yielded by `g`. We can no longer the next value of `gr` (ie. 3) unless somehow we stored all those values or we somehow t-ed off the underlying `g` generator into two independent generators. Neither of these are good solutions for the default implementation (especially since the point of itertools is *not* to do this), so it leaves it up to you to do this, but you need to store these values *before* something causes `next(grouper)` to be called and advance the generator past the values you wanted.

Comment: Do you know by any chance why they made it this way? On a side note, I looked into the pseudocode in the docs. It looks like `__next__()` iterates while the key matches (discarding keys and values), then returns a generator that would iterate until the next key matches (return values of the next key). Although I might be missing something. And `self.id is id` looks like a guard against returning values after the iterator has advanced, yet it's somehow part of the loop's condition.

Comment: @x-yuri, I've added some notes about why this works this way. Hope it helps.